# sinfo command does not show updated information about allocated nodes

Tags: slurm

I wonder why *sinfo* command shows different information than the returned by *squeue*.
I have experienced on several occasions that the number of allocated nodes returned by *sinfo* did not match the allocated nodes showed in *squeue*.

Has anyone noticed this issue?

I'm using the version 17.02, but in previous versions I've also experienced this behavior.

For instance, I've executed squeue and sinfo at the same moment at this is what I get:

```
Thu Aug 24 10:12:50 2017
  JOBID PARTITION             NAME ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
  57011   dmrTest        jacobi-98  R       3:02      4 s07r2b[15-18]
  57012   dmrTest            cg-99  R       3:02      4 s07r2b[11-14]
  57010   dmrTest        jacobi-98  R       3:24     32 s01r1b[39,42,45-48],s07r2b[09-10],s09r2b[54-58,63-64,67],s14r1b[61-62,65-67],s14r2b[49,54-
57,61-63,65],s24r2b[57,59]
  57008   dmrTest         nbody-96  R       3:52      8 s09r1b[53-55,57-59,61-62]
  57009   dmrTest         nbody-97  R       3:52      4 s10r2b[49-50],s14r2b[69,72]
  57007   dmrTest         nbody-95  R       4:21      4 s24r2b[49-52]
  57006   dmrTest            cg-94  R       4:26      4 s14r1b[49-52]
  57004   dmrTest            cg-92  R       4:42      4 s01r1b[33-35,37]
  57003   dmrTest         nbody-91  R       4:45      4 s10r2b[61,63-65]
  57001   dmrTest         nbody-89  R       4:46      8 s10r2b[51-52],s14r2b[50-53],s24r2b[53-54]
  57002   dmrTest            cg-90  R       4:46      2 s24r2b[62-63]
  57000   dmrTest         nbody-88  R       5:00      8 s09r2b[49,51-53],s14r1b[57-60]
  56999   dmrTest         nbody-87  R       5:02      4 s07r2b[19-20,22-23]
  56997   dmrTest            cg-85  R       5:36      8 s01r1b[29-32],s10r2b[53-56]
  56995   dmrTest            cg-83  R       7:08      2 s10r2b[66-67]
  56988   dmrTest        jacobi-76  R       8:28      2 s14r1b[53-54]
  56985   dmrTest            cg-74  R       8:36      4 s09r2b[68-70,72]
  56978   dmrTest            cg-69  R       9:37      2 s14r1b[55-56]
  56976   dmrTest            cg-67  R       9:40      2 s14r1b[63-64]
  56974   dmrTest            cg-65  R      10:49      4 s10r2b[69-70],s24r2b[64-65]
  56973   dmrTest            cg-64  R      10:58      4 s09r1b[49-52]
  56971   dmrTest            cg-62  R      11:22      2 s14r2b[67-68]
  56969   dmrTest            cg-60  R      11:35      2 s24r2b[55-56]
```

If you count the nodes of the *squeue* command, you will see 114 allocated nodes, but if you check the *sinfo*, what you have is:

```
PARTITION AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST
dmrTest*     up   infinite     94  alloc s01r1b[29-35,37,47-48],s07r2b[09-20,22-23],s09r1b[49-55,57-59,61-62],s09r2b[49,51-53,68-70,72],s10r2b[49-56,61,63-67,69-70],s14r1b[49-60,63-64],s14r2b[50-53,67-69,72],s24r2b[49-56,62-65]
dmrTest*     up   infinite     34   idle s01r1b[39,42,45-46],s09r1b[63-66],s09r2b[54-58,63-64,67],s14r1b[61-62,65-67],s14r2b[49,54-57,61-63,65],s24r2b[57,59-61]
```

Only 94 allocated nodes.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you are seeing and expecting?

Comment: @CarlesFenoy edited with an example, thank you.